# Create Linux distribution (tar.zip) of python project from Windows+Eclipse+PyDev

Tags: python, distutils

I am learning and developing an application using `Windows 10`, `Eclipse` + `PyDev` (`Python 3.4.3`).
This application is using 2 more `Python` libraries downloaded from `PyPi` repository.

Now my target system is a `Linux` environment with no internet connectivity.
I would like to install my code inside virtual environment in the system.
I learnt installing the `Python` libraries through `tar.gz` files from different sources.

But I am not sure how to package my code for `Linux` distribution from `Windows`, I don't see any proper options.

Below are my requests:

1. Steps for Packaging `Linux` distribution of my `Python` code from
   `Windows` machine
2. Correct steps for creating Virtual Environment
   activation and Freezing in case of upgrade of my code later (I dont
   clear steps for this)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special to distribute your code for linux (unless you're using some platform-specific features).

You need to package your code properly, with a `setup.py` as detailed in the [packaging projects tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this today. Pls share the virtual environment steps if u have.